# Can I call props.navigation in Flatlist data?

Tags: react-native, view, parameters

I have a const declared which has parameters passed from another page.

```
const obj = this.props.navigation.state.params.item;
const itemArray = Object.values(obj.name)
```

Now, i am calling itemArray in Flatlist data, see below.

Here is my Flatlist:

```
 <FlatList
      key={this.keyExtractor}
      data={itemArray}
      renderItem={({item}) => this.renderText(item)}
    />
```

The problem is that its not displaying the text. Its just blank.

Here is the render method I am calling in Flatlist:

```
renderText = (itt) => {

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <ListItem 
        title={itt.name}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: You should update your question with more details of what you are passing. Currently as it stands this question is unclear.

Comment: @Andrew why did you delete your answer? It helped me soo much, I was about to mark it as an answer. I will also edit my question.

Comment: @Andrew I edited my question. Please check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since FlatList doesn't accept an object you have to do a workaround. You have to also create an array and push your object there.

```
const obj = this.props.navigation.state.params.item;
    var propsArray = [];
    const itemArray = Object.assign(obj)
    propsArray.push(itemArray)

    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          key={this.keyExtractor}
          data={propsArray}
          renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderText(item)}
        />
      </View>
}
```

and your render method should remain the same:

```
renderText = (itt) => {

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <ListItem 
        title={itt.name}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the FlatList.

Here is how I would implement it in the render method of your component.

1. Notice that you don't need to use `this` infront of the `obj` variable.
2. Also you have spelt `item` wrong in your `renderItem` function, that may cause you problems if you don't correct it.
3. The object that you are passing, for this specific code to work, should be an array of strings, something like `['first', 'second', 'third']`
4. Also you should have defined a function as a `keyExtractor` inside your component.

---

```
keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
  return index.toString();
}

render () {
  const obj = this.props.navigation.state.params.item;
  return (
   <FlatList
     key={this.keyExtractor}
     data={obj}
     renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
   />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just dont understand the keyExtractor, how should I do it?

Comment: Added a simple keyExtractor, it should suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use

```
<FlatList
      key={this.keyExtractor}
      data={this.props.navigation.state.params.item}
      renderItem={({ iteemm }) => <Text>{iteemm}</Text>}
/>
```

Comment: Its an object so I cant. Flatlist accepts only arrays, thats the point.

Comment: try this
      `const obj = [];
       obj.push(this.props.navigation.state.params.item);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
renderText = (itt) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <ListItem 
        title={itt}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: I did but it displays everything whats inside that array.

Comment: plz log before return and see `itt.name`